# Is there a bootstrap class specifically for an expanded dropdown menu?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to change the z-index of a bootstrap dropdown to have a higher z-index once it is expanded--so no elements can overlap the listed items. Is there a specific class in the bootstrap library to address this?

Answer (score 0):

The default **dropdown-menu** class has z-index: 1000;

The other classes with an higher z-index are:

- .navbar-fixed-bottom --> z-index: 1030;
- .modal: 1030; --> z-index: 1050;
- .modal-backdrop --> z-index: 1040;
- .tooltip --> z-index: 1070;
- .popover --> z-index: 1060;

So, the highest value is for the class tooltip.

I assume you have to overwrite the dropdown-menu z-index:

```
    .dropdown-menu {
        z-index: 1000; !important;
    }
```